# How to Loop through multiple Database connections skipping on connection error

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, dataset, datasource

I have a VB.Net program, that accesses 10 Databases, and fills 10 different datasets per database.  The program runs automatically at 11PM when we do not have any activity so it didn't matter to me that it was not the fastest way to accomplish it.

However, The problem I have is: if I try to connect to a database that is offline (internet outage, VPN tunnel down, etc. the program will not continue and eventually times out.  Below is a snapshot of my code that is repeated for each site.

```
Me.1TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.1;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
Me.2TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.1;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
Me.3TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.1;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
```

I then build an HTML table with the above information:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><th>Description</th><th> Location </th></tr>
                <%= From opentime In Me.Dataset.1.AsEnumerable _
                    Select <tr><td>Open Time</td>
                        <td><%= 1.TimeIn.ToString("hh:mm tt") %></td>
                        <td width="50"><%= 1.Name %></td></tr> %>
```

etc...

I then go to the next database:

```
Me.1TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.2;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
    Me.2TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.2;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
    Me.3TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.2;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
```

And then I build the table for that database:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><th>Description</th><th> Location </th></tr>
            <%= From opentime In Me.Dataset.1.AsEnumerable _
                Select <tr><td>Open Time</td>
                    <td><%= 1.TimeIn.ToString("hh:mm tt") %></td>
                    <td width="50"><%= 1.Name %></td></tr> %>
```

What Happens is, if the first attempt (Datasource 10.0.1.1) times out, or cannot connect the program doesn't continue, it errors.  How can I get the program to go to the next datasource if it detects an error with the first datasource?  Keep in mind it needs to skip the remaining table adapters (in this example 2, and 3 for Data Source 10.0.1.1).

Comment: Read about exception handling: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315965

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: It grabs the info, puts it in an html table, and then emails the tables to a specified user.

Comment: i understand what it is supposed todo, but what kind of project are you using. I am guesing webforms (.aspx) In that case you could uses repeaters to build te tables, together with the exception handling that paul suggested.

Comment: For me this is more of a fallback mechanism, whereby trying to connect to given online db server/instance. I propose you to follow a 'Stack' approach (stack data structures) and try to peek and pop individual connection string items and subsequently connect or move on to next connection in case of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Try/Catch block for every connection to database.

```
Try
    Me.1TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.1;Initial Catalog=cat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=id;Password=password;Connection Lifetime=0"
    'your code here to create HTML table'
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: You can include in a single Try/Catch block all the connections to the same datasource.

Comment: I'll test this.  If I wanted to log the error to a text file I suppose I would put that in-between the Catch ex As Exception and End Try?

Comment: yes! you can write ex.Message and/or ex.InnerException to log file.